# Math expectation

Tags: probability

There is a vertical pipe. There are $k$ valves inside the pipe. At any given time, the valve can be in one of two states: closed and open. The probability that any particular valve will be opened is $\frac12$ and is independent of the time and condition of the other valves. At time $t=0$, a heavy ball is placed on the upper valve. What is the mathematical expectation of the time it takes for the ball to pass through the entire valve system? We can assume that if at some point in time there is an arbitrary number of open valves on the path of the ball, then it will have time to pass them all until it hits the valve in the "closed" state.

I've tried to solve for $k = 1$:

$E(X_1) = 0\cdot\frac{1}{2} + 1\cdot\frac{1}{2^2} + \ldots = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} k \cdot \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = \frac12 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k} = \frac12 \cdot 2 = 1$
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x} \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} kx^k = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \quad \forall x \in (-1;1)$

Then assume that occasions are independent: $E(X) = E(X_1+\ldots+X_k) = E(X_1) + \ldots + E(X_k) = 1 + \ldots + 1 = k$

Is it correct?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_k$ be the expected time to exit when there are $k$ valves beneath you (so $X_0=0$).  With probability $1/2$ you make no progress and need to wait one time step, and otherwise you pass the first valve and move to the $k-1$ case.  So
$$
X_k = \frac{1}{2}(1 + X_k) + \frac{1}{2}X_{k-1},
$$
or $X_k=X_{k-1}+1$.  The solution is, in fact, $X_k=k$.